# How to link with libstdc++_pic.a with GCC?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries, libstdc++

I have a libstdc++_pic.a on my system (Ubuntu 12.04, gcc 4.6.3), presumably this is the version of libstdc++ created with -fPIC. I also have a libstdc++.a.

I see the following error when I try to statically link libstdc++ with a shared library via the -static-libstdc++ link flag:

`` :-1: error: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++.a(functexcept.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `std::bad_exception::~bad_exception()' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC ``

So I'm assuming it is using the non pic version, as I would expect based on the default naming. How can I instruct the linker to use the libstdc++_pic.a file?

**Update 1**
The _pic version is in the 32 bit gcc subfolder at `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/32`, and I don't see a _pic version in the parent folder where the 64 bit versions are located. It appears that my version of gcc was not compiled with a 64 bit PIC static libstdc++.a.

**Update 2**
I was able to install the 64  bit version of libstdc++_pic.a by checking my gcc version and then installing the package:

`gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-4.6-pic`

And now I see it in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/`. Still need to figure out how to tell linker to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed this by passing the `-nostdlib` linker option, and then explicitly linking libstdc++_pic.

However, now I am getting the following error:

`version node not found for symbol std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_M_move(wchar_t*, wchar_t const*, unsigned long)@@GLIBCXX_3.4.5`

After researching it appears there may have been a bug for static libstdc++ 64bit with pic, which is now addressed in newer versions of gcc (4.7.3). This other question has more information:

[Compiling one shared library on Linux to target all distributions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774453/compiling-one-shared-library-on-linux-to-target-all-distributions)

Comment: Follow-up: I installed and switched to gcc 4.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 (via the test toolchain repository) and my program now links and runs successfully and I can see that the libstdc++ is statically linked in to the shared library. I no longer had to use the libstdc++_pic library as apparently the default one is relocatable (-static-libstdc++ was enough).